# Spring PollableChannel - cannot set loggingEnabled to false?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I wrote the following configuration:

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(BatchProperties.class)
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private BatchProperties properties;

    @Bean
    public PollableAmqpChannel testingChannel(final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        final PollableAmqpChannel channel = new PollableAmqpChannel(properties.getQueue(), rabbitTemplate);
        channel.setLoggingEnabled(false);
        return channel;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "testingChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "1000", maxMessagesPerPoll = "1"))
    public MessageHandler messageHandler(final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate) {
        return message -> {
            log.info("Received: {}", message);
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(properties.getQueue(), message);
        };
    }
}
```

Message gets successfully read and requeued but I keep getting the following message:

> Calling receive with a timeout value on PollableAmqpChannel. The
>   timeout will be ignored since no receive timeout is supported.

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELASE.

I've put a breakpoint on :

```
@Override
public void setLoggingEnabled(boolean loggingEnabled) {
    this.loggingEnabled = loggingEnabled;
}
```

in the `AbstractAmqpChannel` class. It gets called with 'false' (as it should according to my configuration) and then it gets called again each time it polls a message and it is set to 'true'.

I checked the hashcode and it seems it is my bean, but 'loggingEnabled' gets reset to 'true' with each message.

Is there something wrong with my configuration and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug - if you have `spring-integration-jmx` on the classpath, or specify `@EnableIntegrationManagement` on one of your config classes; the `IntegrationManagementConfigurer` bean sets logging enabled to true for all `IntegrationManagement` implementations, overwriting your setting.

Please open a [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

In the meantime, you could add a bean that implements `SmartLifecyle` to set the flag back to false (in the `start()` method); it will run after the `IntegrationManagementConfigurer`.

Of course, you could also set the log category `org.springframework.integration.amqp.channel.PollableAmqpChannel` to `WARN` to achieve the same effect much simpler.

Comment: I thought about setting the logging to WARN, just wanted to know what was going on. Thanks.